# In R, how to stop xtable from automatically rounding?

Tags: r, rounding, dataframe, xtable

How do I disable automatic rounding in this case?

```
> x <- c(2.222, 3.333, 6.6666)
> df <- data.frame(x)
> df
       x
1 2.2220
2 3.3330
3 6.6666
> xtable(df)
```

Results in

```
% latex table generated in R 2.11.1 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Tue Oct 25 12:13:08 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
  1 & 2.22 \\ 
  2 & 3.33 \\ 
  3 & 6.67 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I can't find any option in the [docs of xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf) to turn it off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about `digits`?

```
xtable(df,digits=4)
% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Tue Oct 25 11:39:25 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2.2220 \\ 
  2 & 3.3330 \\ 
  3 & 6.6666 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question. I have a case where I'd like the numbers displayed as is - I've done all the rounding myself and don't, for example, want integers displaying as 121.0000.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by transforming all columns into string, although it could generate some warning message:

```
> xtable(df, display=rep("s",ncol(df)+1))

% latex table generated in R 3.3.3 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Tue Oct 24 12:43:58 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
1 &  2.222 \\ 
  2 &  3.333 \\ 
  3 & 6.6666 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Warning message:
In formatC(x = c(2.222, 3.333, 6.6666), format = "s", digits = 2,  :
  trasformo l'argomento in "character" in format="s"
```

Answer (score 0):

See @James' answer for the correct answer (I didn't even check that as I presumed @mmmasterluke had actually read the docs).

As an alternative you can use `toLatex` from package `memisc`:

```
library(memisc)
x <- c(2.222, 3.333, 6.6666)
df <- data.frame(x)
toLatex(df, digits=4)
```

gives you

```
\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{4}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{x} \\
\midrule
2.2220 \\
3.3330 \\
6.6666 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

And it has loads of other options which you can use to configure your Latex output.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already formatted the data frame with your preferred rounding and don't want to retype the digits for each column, one solution is to turn everything into text.  I just defined a function that I then use elsewhere in place of `xtable`:

```
myxtable <- function(x, ...) xtable(apply(x, 2, as.character), ...)
```

Then the return value of `myxtable` can be used wherever you'd use the return value of `xtable`, but with formatting intact.